# smartgwt ToolStripButton icon on disabled form

Tags: smartgwt

I have used ToolStripButton which is added in ToolStrip. I have set icon on the buttons and by default button is disabled. problem is icon only shown on button when it is enabled. and but I want to show icon in disabled form of button too.

Answer (score 1):

When a ToolStripButton becomes disabled, the URL of the icon gets "_disabled" added to it.  So you'll see a 404 in the Net tab of Firebug from the attempt to fetch that icon.  Just put the image file for the disabled version of your icon at that URL.

Answer (score 0):

One small clarification. In my case smarGWT is looking for icon with "_Disabled" appended (with first letter in uppercase). Hope this will save someone time :)